# LiteDB - find data object via List.contains

Tags: list, where-clause, litedb

A simplified version. I have two classes:

```vb
Public Class mSystem

    Public Property ID as ObjectID
    Public Property Name as string

End Class

Public Class mEmulator

    Public Property ID as ObjectID
    Public Property Name as string
    <BsonRef("mSystems")>
    Public Property AssociatedSystems as New List(Of mSystem)

End Class

Public Class Main

    Public Sub EmaultorsLinkedToSystem      

        dim SelectedSystem as mSystem = db.Collections.mSystems.Find(Function(x) x.Name = "Sony Playstation").FirstOrDefault

        test = db.Collections.mEmulators.Include(Function(x) x.AssociatedSystems).Find(Function(y) y.AssociatedSystems.Contains(SelectedSystem)).ToList

    End sub 

End Class
```

Now I know one mEmulator data object has "Sony Playstation" in its List(of mSystem). However, `test` returns null. Why isn't this finding it? I've tried a few permutations, but cant get this to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The `Include` method is used for resolving references to other collections, and you're not using `BsonRef` with `AssociatedSystems` (at least not in this example you provided). In your example, the instances of `mSystem` in `AssociatedSystems` are not being stored in a separate collection, but as an array of embedded documents in the emulators collection.

Try removing the `Include` call, it should work fine.

Comment: Just come back to this as had same problem. You were right, I omitted the  <BsonRef("mSystems")>. OP changed. How would I achieve the desired outcome in this instance?